# Lotus notes data folder contents getting deleted

Tags: lotus-notes

Lotus Notes 8.5.1(Multiple User) Standard Edition is installed on a server running Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition Service Pack.

Lotus Notes is accessed by multiple users using Citrix(Presentation Server) . All the user data folders are kept in the root of d:\ drive .

Everything works as expected but one day I suddenly find that all the folders except the IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT folder  under the notes\data folder for a particular user have been deleted .

I have no idea how these folders are getting deleted. I googled a lot for a solution to this problem but did not come up with any solution.

Comment: Are you sure there are now singel user installs involved? Otherwise, Open a PMR with IBM.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Lotus notes is installed in multiuser mode

Answer (score 0):

Disable the "Multi-user Cleanup Service". You administrator may have a roaming policy in place that is set to delete a users data directory after a given time.